# Gradient color for each category to generate a heatmap table using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, heatmap

I am trying to generate a heatmap table using ggplot in **R**. My data looks this:

```
dt <- cbind(rbinom(1:10,100,0.9), rbinom(1:10,100,0.5), rbinom(1:10,100,0.2), rbinom(1:10,100,0.05)
colnames(dt) <- c("A","B","C","D")
```

I want to use different gradient colors for each category to emphasize the importance of each value. Since the range of values is large, the smaller number will be colored almost same. That's why, I want to use different colors. My code is here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)

dt <- cbind(rbinom(1:10,100,0.9), rbinom(1:10,100,0.5), rbinom(1:10,100,0.2), rbinom(1:10,100,0.01))
colnames(dt) <- c("A","B","C","D")

dt <- melt(dt)

dt %>%
    ggplot(aes(Var2,Var1)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white") +
    geom_text(aes(fill = dt$value, label = dt$value, 3), size = 4) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow", high = "red", midpoint = 0.05) +
theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, size = 10, face = "bold"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
ggtitle("Heatmap Table") +
theme(legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14)) +
scale_x_discrete(name = "") +
scale_y_discrete(name = "") +
labs(fill = "Heatmap")
```

The plot looks like this:

[image: Heatmap table]

The colors should be gradient in each category. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm noticing issues in your `geom_text` right away. You don't want to refer back to the dataframe by name---change `label = dt$value` to just `label = value`. `geom_text` also doesn't have a fill, so that argument doesn't do anything. Also, what's the purpose of the 3 in the `geom_text` `aes`? It gives all the texts the same x coordinate, making them overlap each other.

Comment: 3 in the geom_text aes was a typo. Can I use different colors for each category?

Comment: I don't think you can use different sets of colors---you're creating a color scale from one variable. Green is missing because I didn't change the midpoint in the color gradient, so I'll fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I'm interpreting your question correctly, I changed the variable that is mapped to fill. Instead of the raw value you have, I grouped by Var2 and calculated a relative value, so each value is scaled compared to the other values in its group---e.g. how does this value compare to all others in group A.

I also took out the 3 from your `geom_text` `aes` because it seemed like a typo. That lets the text geoms each take the same positions as the corresponding tiles.

One drawback to this approach is that the labels on the legend don't have a lot of meaning now, or at least would need some explanation to say that values are scaled against their group.

**Edit**: I'm changing the midpoint in the color gradient to 0.5 instead of the previous 0.05, so the minimum colors still show after scaling values.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)

dt <- cbind(rbinom(1:10,100,0.9), rbinom(1:10,100,0.5), rbinom(1:10,100,0.2), rbinom(1:10,100,0.01))
colnames(dt) <- c("A","B","C","D")

dt <- melt(dt)

dt %>%
    group_by(Var2) %>%
# make a variable for the value scaled in relation to other values in that group
    mutate(rel_value = value / max(value)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Var2,Var1)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = rel_value), colour = "white") +
# take out dt$...
# take out 3 from aes
    geom_text(aes(label = value), size = 4) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow", high = "red", midpoint = 0.5) +
    theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
                panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
                axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, size = 10, face = "bold"),
                plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
                axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
    ggtitle("Heatmap Table") +
    theme(legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14)) +
    scale_x_discrete(name = "") +
    scale_y_discrete(name = "") +
    labs(fill = "Heatmap")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you for the response, @camille. It perfectly worked.